# Visual Studio AWS Serverless Application with Cognito/OIDC gets ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I installed AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2019 & created new "AWS Serverless Application(.NET Core C#)"  project.

Following this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/sUAXCv86BuE) I configured new Cognito User Pool & edited the default project's **Startup.cs** & added secure page with [Authorize] attribute (at the 12min mark you can find the exact steps of how Cognito was configured).

After publishing to AWS (or even when debugging locally) when I navigate to secure page I correctly get redirected and prompted to login, but after successful login it enters a loop in the background that keeps sending back to OIDC authorization link & back to my site... after a few of those it throws an error of "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

Any idea what is missing from this tutorial in order to make it work properly?  The only step I skipped was that he registered a domain name for his site, while I'm just using the default site URL I get after right-clicking project & choosing "Publish to AWS Lambda".

Here's edited code of my **Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string clientId = "<cognito_app_client_id>";
    string clientSecret = "<cognito_app_client_secret>";
    string logoutUrl = "https://<published_app_aws_url>/logout";
    string baseUrl = "https://<published_app_aws_url>";
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.MetadataAddress = $"https://cognito-idp.<aws_region>.amazonaws.com/<cognito_pool_id>/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.ClientId = clientId;
        options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
            {
                var logoutUri = logoutUrl;
                logoutUri += $"client_id={clientId}&logout_uri={baseUrl}";
                context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
                context.HandleResponse();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Cognito expert, but this Workshop might be helpful: https://net-immersionday.workshop.aws/9-how-to-authenticate-users-in-my-application/application-configuration-and-integration/review-net-app.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comment by Philip Pittle I found the UseAuthentication must come before UseAuthorization.